Does Sveltekit with no SSR work on normal ftp-server and php-api webhost?
Im a little confused about Sveltekit,
Does it work on a normal webhost like one.com, if I turn of SSR? Does it still need nodejs or similar?
Will it work with a php-api?
I have searched the www, and found something that indicated, that it would work, but it wasnt totally clear.

SvelteKit at its core is host agnostic. Via the use of adapters an application can be deployed in various environments.
For a simple file server you would want the adapter for static site generation. When using this, the pages cannot have a dynamic server part, that means that they either have to be server-side pre-rendered (which allows server operations, e.g. fetching data for the construction of the page during build) or use client-side rendering.
The result will be static files with or without JS.
